# Pushing a Value & Accessing Nested JSON in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework, lodash

Im having trouble pushing a value to my nested data inside my Ionic/Angular Project.

I'd like to add a boolean value to each day's time (if it has one) where my json looks like this (I am retrieving the json over a strict http call so its tree structure must not be changed).

```
{
     "all_year": true,
  "season_from": "01/01",
  "season_to": "12/31",
  "monday": [
    "08:30am"
  ],
  "tuesday": [
    "08:30am"
  ],
  "wednesday": [
    "08:00am", "09:30am", "01:30pm"
  ],
  "thursday": [
    "08:30am", "09:30am"
  ],
  "friday": [
    "08:30am"
  ],
  "saturday": [],
  "sunday": []
}
```

> My result look like this 
>   [image]

my html

```
 <ion-list ng-repeat="(key, value) in filteredDays"
                    ng-model="value.checked" 
                    ng-checked ="value.checked">
          <div class="item item-divider">
               <h3>{{key}}</h3><!--{{value}}--></div>
          <ion-toggle ng-repeat="x in value"
                             ng-model="value" 
                  ng-checked="x" 
                    >
           {{x}}
             </ion-toggle>
```

my js

```
  $scope.filteredDays={};
     $scope.unFilteredDays = {
             "all_year": true,
          "season_from": "01/01",
          "season_to": "12/31",
          "monday": [
            "08:30am"
          ],
          "tuesday": [
            "08:30am"
          ],
          "wednesday": [
            "08:00am", "09:30am", "01:30pm"
          ],
          "thursday": [
            "08:30am", "09:30am"
          ],
          "friday": [
            "08:30am"
          ],
          "saturday": [],
          "sunday": []
      };
    $scope.filteredDays = $scope.unFilteredDays;

//THIS IS WHERE IM STUCK

/*
  var checked = false;
   $scope.filteredDays.forEach($scope.filteredDays, function(value, key) {
   $scope.filteredDays.push(checked);
 });
```

*/

I left a comment of where I am stuck, I cannot seem to figure out how to push a boolean to the time toggle item array. I setup a [codepen here](http://codepen.io/garrettmac/pen/mVdQVx)

In addition I've tried working with lodash in this project to handle the data (and get "all_year","season_from","season_to" values out of the list) and believe I have it set up correctly, however, I'm too inexperienced with it to get it to do what I'd like.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just make an array of day names and check the key name against it. If it's in the day name array then add the Boolean. You can use _.contains or plain old indexOf to check the key

Comment: Do you think you could make this another answer and show me how I could accomplish that I'm still figuring out lodash @vbranden

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.filteredDays` is not an Array, so doesn't have the `forEach` method. Instead of this:

```
var checked = false;
$scope.filteredDays.forEach(function(newCheckItem) {
    newCheckItem.checked = checked;
});
```

try this:

```
var checked = false;
Object.keys($scope.filteredDays).forEach(function(key) {
    $scope.filteredDays[key].checked = checked;
});
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to break it but it does seem to push the checked Boolean

Answer (score 0):

```
var dayNames = ["sunday ", "monday",... Etc];
_.forEach($scope.filteredDays, function(v, day) {
  if (_.contains(dayNames, day)) {
    v.push(checked);
  }
});
```